spring boot 2.5.6 without spring security and security config upgraded to spring boot 3 making swagger not working
When trying to upgrade my spring boot project from 2.5.6 to 3.2.5 swagger UI stops working.
In version 2.5.6, I do not have spring security nor security config. I have only SwaggerConfig :
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationId;

     @Value("${spring.application.description}")
    private String description;

     @Value("${spring.application.version}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${app.env}")
    private String env;

     @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI() {
             return new OpenAPI()
                     .info(apiInfo())
                   .components(new Components());
    }

    private Info apiInfo(){
        Info info= new Info();
            info.setTitle(env + " - " + applicationId);
            info.setDescription(description);
            info.version(version);
        return info;
    }
}

Is it necessary to add spring security after upgrading to spring boot 3.2.5, or should i change my SwaggerConfig? Or is the problem somewhere else?
Thank you very much and have a good day.

It seems like the compatibility issue in your case might be due to SpringFox not being updated since July 2020, and its latest version, 3.0.0, only supports Spring Boot 2.0.0.
You might need to switch to SpringDoc, which is compatible with Spring Boot 3.0.0 and onwards.
This migration guide will be a great help to you
Gradle
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.2.0'

Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

SwaggerConfig
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
 public OpenAPI openAPI() {
  return new OpenAPI()
   .info(new Info()
    .title("Title of the API")
    .description("Description of the API.")
    .version("Version of the API"));
 }
}

References Docs

Spring boot 3 doesn't work with springfox 3.0
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/4017
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

have a nice day - kevin

thank you very much for your answer.
Indeed, adding springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui was part of the solution.
However, even after that, I had a login interface to access Swagger-UI.
In order to fix that and have direct access to swagger I added a security config :
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(httpMethods());
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }

    private static List<String> httpMethods() {
        return List.of(HEAD.name(), GET.name(), POST.name(), PUT.name(), PATCH.name(), DELETE.name(), OPTIONS.name(), TRACE.name());
    }


    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

adding a security config with Spring boot 3 requires following Maven dependencies :
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>


Personally, it seems like the accurate answer to this question is my answer. It's a bit disappointing that you didn't choose my answer, which you accepted yourself, but I'll respect your choice.
Have a good day.

Well, the answer you gave might be better documented, but it was an uncomplete answer for my case. It still did not work for me. I'll accept your answer since it might be more helpfull in a general case, it's whatever for me if it can make your day better. Thanks for the help.
